# White space at the bottom of the page on tablet/phone

Tags: android, css, web

I use a image as page background, this is the code:

```
    body {
    background-color: black;
    background: url(/images/bg.jpg); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 100% 0%;
}
```

It looks okay on computer but if I open the page from a tablet or phone there is white space at the bottom of the page.

Here is how it should look:
[image: how it should look]

And here is how it looks on tablet:
[image: tablet view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try,

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: is the issue fixed?

Comment: Uh, it worked somehow, but there is still a small issue, check the image below, still a bit of white on the right and at the bottom:
http://m.imgur.com/vIA6hZB

And yes.. I need to fix the video too..

Comment: can you please try to change, background-position: 0 0; or center

Comment: It fixed the white space on the right, the one at the bottom from the above image is still there.

Comment: can you share me a screenshot?

Comment: just try   html, body{
  height: 100%; margin: 0;
}

Comment: just remove background-attachment fixed  and background position center center

Comment: Still the same :/

Comment: is there any border on the bottom tile?

Comment: ok one more can you please check the image has any white outline?

Comment: Oh nevermind, it is fixed, looks like cache issues, thanks, now I have to wait few more days to ask for help regarding the youtube embed xD

Answer (score 0):

Due to different aspect ratios of the image itself and tablets (many of them), you will always get some blank space when you use cover. Using height 100% will actually cover the entire height, but will stretch the image.

What you may need is to compare the aspect ratios of the image and the screen of the device and then try to use background-size (percentages) to zoom in or out of the image in order to cover everything in all devices.